# Allowed memory size of (...) exhausted

Tags: theme-development, memory

I'm stuck trying to figure out what seems to be a very common problem, the above mentioned "Allowed memory size of (...) exhausted". After developing my first theme I was moving it (just the theme, not the whole WP installation) from my development computer to my production server. After installing WP everything seemed fine and the site was working great with the default theme. Upon activating my custom theme however WP started throwing the error,

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in
>   /srv/www/my.domain.com/public_html/wp-includes/cache.php on line 113

Worth mentioning is that I've never had any issues like this during development.

I've tried to increase both the memory limit in php.ini as well as setting the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT constant in wp-config without luck.

```
php -i | grep memory
memory_limit => 128M => 128M

cat wp-config.php | grep MEMORY
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

As you can see I've worked my way up to 128M. Still hitting the error I'm thinking this is getting ridiculous and not likely the source of my problem. As far as I can recall I never had to go much beyond 32M on much larger WP installations in the past.

Comment: Works the settings of Memory Limit? Also a chance to set via `ini_set( 'memory_limit', WP_MEMORY_LIMIT );` after your settings in the wp-config.php.

Comment: have you tried to turn off plugins?

Comment: @bueltge Sure, I'll try that.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Yes, in the sense that the site doesn't have any.

Comment: Without seeing code it's hard to say, but you want to look for any loops `for` `foreach` `while` which are allocating memory. Chances are you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Waldermort Thanks, I'll have a look. If I can't find anything I'll be sure to update my original post with my theme code.

Comment: What about your functions.php file? Maybe you have some bad code there. Is your theme using a framework?

Comment: @Waldermort You certainly pointed me in the right direction. The problem was that I hadn't created a theme / navigation menu in my new WP installation and didn't run checks for that in the code. Post your comment as an answer and I'm willing to accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help. My comment doesn't contain an answer, so posting it as an answer would not be in the nature of this site. I recommend you post an answer to your own question to help future users ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this issue was caused by bad code (a missing assert) in my theme. More specifically the theme requires a custom navigation menu. As this menu hadn't been created and assigned the site crashed. Why this caused an memory exhaustion error on my production server and not my development computer I unfortunately don't know.

Answer (score -1):

Sometime  ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

gives error if you don't have permission to change.

This will work fine if you have permission to change the limits.

This you find in mysql if you are using mysql database

Path for finding the answer is

mysql\bin\my.ini

ini_set('memory_limit, -1'); overrides the default PHP memory limit.

Another answer will be by modifying .htaccess file 
Open or create the .htaccess file in the root folder and add the following code:
1 php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
2 php_value post_max_size 64M

Again, it is important that we emphasize that if you are on a shared hosting package, then these techniques may not work. In that case, you would have to contact your web hosting provider to increase the limit for you.

Comment: Please explain why you are suggesting this code for a site. What are the consequences that can happen if the code is implemented. Edit and elaborate your answer to make it more informative and appropriate.

Comment: I suppose for debugging purposes that is an option, but like the comment above suggest this isn't something I would put in production.